# How to wrap text in li to be as long as the width of ul?

Tags: html, css

I want each text in each `<li>` to have the same width as the width of the `<ul>`. But somehow it doesn't work, the text just keeps going and going... I read somewhere on here that giving `<ul>` a width will solve the problem, but it doesn't work in my case. This is my HTML:

```
<div id="chat-wrapper" style="display:none;">
<div id="main-content">
    <div id="user-list-wrapper">
        <b>USERS</b>

        <ul id="user-list">
        </ul>

    </div>

        <div id="messages-main">
            <ul id="messages"></ul>
        </div>
<input id="message-input" placeholder="Your message here!" autofocus="autofocus"/>
<input type="button" id="datasend" value="send"/>
 </div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
#user-list-wrapper {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    border-right:1px solid black;
    height:300px;
    overflow:scroll-y;
}

#login-wrapper {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:50%;
}

#messages-main {
    height:320px; 
    width:950px; 
    overflow:none;
    float:left;
    margin-left:20px;
}
#message-input {
    width:500px; 
    outline:none; 
    height:100px;
    margin-left:300px;
    line-height:100px;
}
#datasend{
}
#main-content {
    width:100%;
    height: 350px;
}
#messages {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    width:900px;
}
#messages li {
    width:100%;
    padding:3px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;
}
#user-list {
    padding:0;
}
#user-list li{
    padding:3px;
    list-style:none;
    border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;
}
```

But this doesn't work for me. What do I have to do to achieve what I want in my case? Thanks.

**UPDATE:** I added the exact code I have.

**UPDATE 2: The text exceeds also `#main-content`.** So it's not only the `<ul>`

Comment: Not sure I understand. You want the li to have the same with as ul.This is already what you have. Then you say the tex keeps going and going. This is not what you want => http://jsfiddle.net/xAA6H/ ?

Comment: This works perfectly: [http://jsfiddle.net/HPYpZ/1/show/](http://jsfiddle.net/HPYpZ/1/show/). What is that you're expecting that isn't happening?

Comment: This may need more precision on what is your result and what you're looking for. One thing i can say is that your li's width will be larger than your ul's width because of the padding.

Comment: I want li to stay inside of the ul. That it doesn't exceed the width of ul.

Comment: @Loolooii remove the padding from the width. New width for li should be (900 - 3 - 3) = 894px (left and right padding)

Comment: @ComputerArts the first example is exactly what I don't want to see and I see right now. Please look at the new code I posted.

Comment: @Abody97 Can you look at the new code please? I think my problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @Loolooii What's wrong with this: [http://jsfiddle.net/J5WXb/3/show/](http://jsfiddle.net/J5WXb/3/show/)?

Comment: @Abody97 , I'm using node.js + socket.io and I had to restart my server. Sorry, it work now :)

Comment: @Loolooii I guess no answer is accepted, then :)

Answer (score 10):

If you are using css3 you can try adding

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

to the li css

Answer (score 4):

You need to put 100% for li element.  Here's an example, http://jsfiddle.net/HQPGS/

Comment: As others have said, the only thing left is the padding.

Comment: The <li> exceeds the <ul> more than the padding. It doesn't matter how long the text is, it doesn't to to the next line ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can put "width: inherit" for li and set a width for ul

Answer (score 0):

you have to add 3 css properties to li to make it:

```
li {
    overflow:hidden; 
    white-space:no-wrap; 
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

but list-style-type will disapprear with option "overflow:hidden", and i have no idea how to get it apprear.